# Emscripten Static Linking to OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, clang, webassembly, emscripten

I am trying to link my C program compiled to WebAssembly using Emscripten (emcc) with OpenSSL statically. I have already compiled OpenSSL from source (downloaded straight from GitHub) to LLVM byte code using `emconfigure` and `emmake`. This yielded `libcrypto.3.dylib` and `libcrypto.a`. As simplicity rather than binary size is important to me, I want to statically link libcrypto to my main program. I tried compiling it using the below command:

`emcc crypto.c ./openssl/libcrypto.a -I./openssl/include -s WASM=1 -o index.html --ignore-dynamic-linking`

But, no luck, when attempting to run my WebAssembly binary using the default index.html, I still get the error:

`To use dlopen, you need to use Emscripten's linking support, see https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/wiki/Linking`

Am I missing something? I am new to Emscripten and got to this point using my previous experience with clang and some reference to the Emscripten documentation (particularly the aforementioned guidance on dynamic linking, which I chose to forgo). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I also realize that OpenSSL may be attempting to invoke a dynamic linkage to a system library as well, I am wondering if there is a way to check some sort of call stack to inspect what dynamic linkage that the webassembly is failing to resolve.

Comment: You can look for the use of dlopen.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Usually I would use GDB but for WebAssembly?

Comment: You can't run a GDB. You should look into the source code.

Comment: And running a crypto on the web is highly discouraged. It's not safe.

Comment: I understand the security concerns this is a learning project and not a security sensative application. I'll take a look at the OpenSSL source (which I am assuming you are referring to and not the WASM byte code)

Comment: Perhaps openssl has a mode where everything is statically linked.  grep for dlopen in the source code and see if there s a macro to disable its use.